# Волновой алгоритм Ли

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

#define n 6

int G[6][6]{
{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}
};

void Lee(int S, int F) {
    S--;
    F--;
    int length, wawe[n];
    vector<int> NewFront, OldFront;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        wawe[i] = -1;

    wawe[S] = 0;
    cout << "Wawe: " << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        cout << wawe[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    OldFront.push_back(S);
    cout << "NewFront: {} " << endl;
    cout << "OldFront: " <<S+1<< endl; 
    length = 0;
    cout << "Length " << length<<endl<<endl;
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < OldFront.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (G[OldFront[i]][j] == 1&&wawe[j]) {
                    if (wawe[j] == -1) {
                        if (j == F) { 
                            wawe[j]++;
                            NewFront.push_back(j);
                            break; 
                        }
                       
                        wawe[j]++;
                    }
                       
                    NewFront.push_back(j);
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Wawe: " << endl;
        for (int k = 0;k<n; k++) {
            cout <<wawe[k]<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "NewFront: " << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < NewFront.size(); k++) {
           cout << NewFront[k]+1 << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "OldFront: " << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < OldFront.size(); k++) {
            cout << OldFront[k]+1 << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "length " << length+1 << endl;
        cout << endl;
        if (NewFront.empty()) {
            cout << "Нет пути";
            break;
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < NewFront.size(); m++) {
            if (NewFront[m] == F) {
                cout <<endl<< "Путь найден" << endl;
                for (int d = F; d >= 0; d--) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        if (G[d][j] && wawe[d] - wawe[d - 1] == 1) cout << d+1 << " ";
                    }
                }
cout <<"Длина пути: "<<length+1;
                return;
            }
        }
        OldFront = NewFront;
        NewFront = {};
        length++;
    }

}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Lee(1, 6);
    
}
```

Пытаюсь написать алгоритм ли в соответствии с википедией. Но я не понимаю,как восстановить путь. Длина у меня выводится,а путь без понятия как вывести. И вообще возможно ли вывести не только один кратчайший путь,но и все возможные кратчайшие пути(их 3 в моем графе).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кратчайших путей для манхеттенской метрики может быть очень много, даже для простых случаев. (Их число растет экспоненциально.) Поэтому, обычно, находят один путь.

Чтобы найти путь: построим функцию отвечающей на вопрос "каков был последний шаг, перед попаданием в заданную точку". Для этого обходим всех соседей заданной точки, и если для одного из соседей разница значений массива wave для этих точек равна ровно весу ребра (1 - если работаем без весов), значит пришли в заданную точку, пришли из этого соседа.
Теперь в цикле движемся от конечной точки к начальной.

Если нужно найти все пути, то нужно возвращать всех соседей, из которых мы могли бы приди в заданную точку.

Comment: ну я вроде бы так и делаю,но что-то не так тут
 for (int d = F; d >= 0; d--) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

                        if (G[d][j] && wawe[d] - wawe[d - 1] == 1) cout << d+1 << " ";

                    }
                }

Comment: `d-1` это не сосед  узла d, а просто узел и соседним порядковым номером. В узел d мы попадаем из узла j в ваших обозначениях.

Comment: аа,понял,спасибо

Comment: я поменял и че-то выводит 6 6 5 4 4 3 2.У меня вообще 3 кратчайших пути. 1-2-4-6,1-3-4-6,1-3-5-6. Можешь именно написать мне этот кусок кода пж?

Comment: @MaximLeo , не зная что и как именно вы исправили, найти ошибку невозможно. После исправления ошибки в заполнении wawe `wawe[j]++` -> `wawe[j] = length+1;` и в цикле печати у меня все работает. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Gqjn6Ycov

Comment: спасибо,теперь реально работает